# How can i assign particular value to properties in a collection?

Tags: c#, autofixture

```
public PNDTicketNumberIsUniqueValidatorTests()
{
    _fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
    _validator = new PNDTicketNumberIsUniqueValidator();

    var pnd = _fixture.Build<PenaltyNotice>()
        .OmitAutoProperties()
        .Create();

    _fixture.Inject(pnd);

    _model = _fixture.Build<CaseModel>().OmitAutoProperties().With(w => w.PenaltyNoticeDisorders).Create();

    _model.PenaltyNotices[0].IdNumber = "12345";
    _model.PenaltyNotices[1].IdNumber = "4654";
    _model.PenaltyNotices[2].IdNumber = "87745";
}
```

After this setup, every penalty notice has the same IdNumber.

After stepping through the code, before any IdNumber assignment they are all null.
After the first assignment they are all 12345.
After the second they are all 4654
After the third they are all 87745

I want to be able to assign specific values to specific properties... Is there enough information here to see why this wouldn't be working, or for ideas where to look?

Comment: You’ll need to show us the definition of CaseModel and what any fixture building customisations do.

Comment: Is PenaltyNotices' all members has same instance of PenaltyNotice ? Can you check setting value of any other member of PenaltyNotice ?

Comment: ok - so trying other properties meant yielded the same kind of results... the property was set at the same value for all members of PenaltyNotice. i'll have to find a better way to populate this collection. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn’t spot it at first, but by using

```
_fixture.Inject(pnd);
```

...you’re basically saying to AutoFixture: “whenever you need to create a `PenaltyNotice`, use (the single instance) `pnd`”. Hence you end up with the same instance in every member of your collection.

What you probably intended was instead

```
_fixture.Register<PenaltyNotice>(() => _fixture
    .Build<PenaltyNotice>()
    .OmitAutoProperties()
    .Create());
```

Similar to `Inject`, but now each time AutoFixture creates a `PenaltyNotice` it uses that function to create a new instance instead.